# Expected value of RV based on matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, asymptotics, expected-value

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around the following problem, let alone approach and attempt to solve it. Perhaps I could achieve more intuition on this with further explanation/example.

> A matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ is chosen at random, where each element is chosen uniformly and independently from among the numbers $1, \dots , \sqrt{n}$. We will look at submatrices (not necessarily continuous) of size $2 \times 2$. Such a submatrix is defined by choosing two different rows $r,s$ and two different columns $c,d$. Such a submatrix is called "good" if all four elements in it are equal. Let's mark with $X$ the
> number of good submatrices. Express $E[X]$ in big $O$ notation.

---

My main thoughts are that there are a total of $n^2$ elements, we're 'randomly' choosing 4 elements(cant choose the same element twice), one has some value and each of the other 3 has a $\frac{1} {\sqrt n}$ probability of being the same, therefor, i got that the probability of getting a "good" submatrix is:
$\frac{n^2 \choose 4 }{(n^2)^4}\cdot \frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3}$, calculating the expected value through that shoulden't be too difficult.

I am really unsure of my probability, I feel like I'm missing an important part.

Comment: Don't you mean "not necessarily contiguous" submatrices?

Comment: Indeed, I had a difficult time expressing the problem. Luckily, my question got edited to a more correct explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the probability of getting a "good" submatrix to calculate ${\bf E}\{X\}$. (Incidentally, I'm not sure that your calculation for that is correct.)

To get the expected value, you only need to calculate the probability that a given $2\times 2$ submatrix is "good", which, as you say, is $n^{-3/2}$. Then you apply linearity of expectation to all these indicator random variables and sum over the number of such submatrices, which is ${n\choose 2}{n\choose 2}$. (Because you're only asked for the big-$O$, you can play a little fast and loose with constants here.) Hope this helped!